# ORA-22920: row containing the LOB value is not locked with JSF

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, jsf, primefaces

I am developing a software, i am using jsf,primefaces and oracle database, when i want to save or load or show a record from a table that has clob i am getting "ORA-22920: row containing the LOB value is not locked". i searched everywhere but i could not find any solution. My code is like this.

Model.java

```
private Clob sut;

    try {
                if( sut != null )
                {
                    return sut.getSubString(1,(int) sut.length());
                }
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return "";
        }
        public void setSutString(String str)
        {
            try {
                sut.setString(1, str);
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        public Clob getSut() {
            return sut;
        }

        public void setSut(Clob sut) {
            this.sut = sut;
        }
```

Hibernate file

```
<property name="sut" type="java.sql.Clob" update="true" insert="true" >
        <column name="SUT" />
    </property>
```

XHtml file

```
 <h:outputLabel for="short_description10" value="#{languageBean.getValue('SUT')}" /> 
                    <p:inputTextarea id ="short_description10" value="#{recordBean.selectedRecord.sutString}" 
                    rows="5" cols="30" autoResize="false" disabled="#{recordBean.editableFieldRecord}" style="width: 490px"/>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have encountered the same problem once upon a time, you are on the right path however you need to pay attention to the following issue:

When you "setString" of the clob, it connects to the database, and tries to update the field of the related row, without having the lock. You will either try to begin a transaction and lock the related row  by UPGRADE flag, and then commit, or you will follow a very simple approach which was my solution to the problem,

When reading the string value of the clob, exactly your approach will be used, however when you write to the clob, create a new clob object with the updated value and assign it to the clob object. This will force to update the clob field to be updated together with the object itself, where hibernate will take care of locking the current row. That's it!

```
        private Clob sut;

        try {
            if( sut != null )
            {
                return sut.getSubString(1,(int) sut.length());
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return "";
    }
    public void setSutString(String str)
    {
        Clob newValue = new ClobImpl(str);
    this.setSut( newValue );
    }

    public Clob getSut() {
        return sut;
    }

    public void setSut(Clob sut) {
        this.sut = sut;
    }
```